# Notation of * in hash function of identity-based encryption

Tags: identity-based-encryption

$H:\{0,1\}^{*} \rightarrow Z_{p}^{*}$

$H:\{0,1\}^{*}  \rightarrow  Z_{p}$

$H:\{0,1\}^{*}  \rightarrow  G_{1}^{*}$

$H:\{0,1\}^{*}  \rightarrow  G_{1}$

Difference meaning of $Z_{p}^{*}, Z_{p},G_{1}^{*},G_{1}$ ??

Comment: Please always try and include a reference to the specification where you found the notation. Often the notation is context specific or it may help us to answer the question.

Comment: Maarten Bodewes.Authenticated Identity-based encryption By Ben Lynn, Identity-based encryption from the weil pairing By Dan Boneh, Matthew Franklin

Comment: The "*" symbols mean completely different things on the left and right side. Left side means repeat a bit, e.g. {0,1} an arbitrary number of times. Right side means, all elements but the zero element.